# Developer Story timeline is messed up in Story View

Tags: bug, profile-page, developer-story

If you look at my [*Developer Story* in *Story View*](https://stackoverflow.com/story/gustavbrock), it is completely messed up.

All items seem joined to the timeline **at random**, most notably the new assessment from PluralSight.

Questions about the timeline has been brought up before - mostly requesting an option for manually to rearrange the entries.

That would be nice, of course, but in the meantime, couldn't the entries just be ordered by date?

Comment: May I suggest adding a link to said page?

Comment: _f you look at my Developer Story in Story View_ .. I guess you havent made it public.. I suggest a screenshot of the problem

Comment: @Cerbrus: That was a very good suggestion. Done: [Gustav](https://stackoverflow.com/story/gustavbrock)

Comment: @SurajRao: Oh, I thought it was. It should be by now.

Comment: Note that items on the timeline are placed by the *end date*, not the start. The items at the top of the timeline are all technically current which is why they appear above the Pluralsight assessment. The blog items are difficult to comment on as most of them don't have dates. Perhaps you could update them to include that information?

Comment: @DavidG: Please make that comment an answer. Editing the dates - where possible - seem to bring the entries into order. Thanks!

Comment: Clearly it _should_ be using a time-line based on seconds since Epoch.

Comment: Ooh thanks for letting me know about this PluralSight connection feature. That's a nice way to beef up my Story :D

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Note that items on the timeline are positioned by the *end date*, not the start.

The items at the top of the timeline are all still *current* which is why they appear above the Pluralsight assessment as that has a definitive date.

The blog items are difficult to comment on as most of them don't have dates. You could update them to include that information though which would enable you to position them correctly.

Comment: That did it. And those marked _Current_ bubble to the top.